# Не работает Github с Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, git, github

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Локальная фиксация изменений (коммит) происходит нормально, но при попытке запушить этот коммит вылезает окно (фото). Просит ввести сначала username, а потом password. Ввожу корректное имя пользователя и пароль от сайта, но потом вылезает ошибка при пуше

```
Открытие репозиториев:
C:\Users\username\Desktop\practics
Отмена edit: C:\Users\username\practics\5\5.cpp
Фиксация bc95ed3e, созданного локально в репозитории C:\Users\username\Desktop\practics
Отправка main

����ࠡ�⠭��� �᪫�祭��: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Custom certificate bundle not found at path: D:/Программы/visual studio/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
   � GitCredentialManager.HttpClientFactory.CreateClient()
   � Atlassian.Bitbucket.OAuth2ClientRegistry..ctor(ICommandContext context)
   � Atlassian.Bitbucket.BitbucketAuthentication..ctor(ICommandContext context)
   � Atlassian.Bitbucket.BitbucketHostProvider..ctor(ICommandContext context)
   � GitCredentialManager.Program.Main(String[] args)

����ࠡ�⠭��� �᪫�祭��: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Custom certificate bundle not found at path: D:/Программы/visual studio/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
   � GitCredentialManager.HttpClientFactory.CreateClient()
   � Atlassian.Bitbucket.OAuth2ClientRegistry..ctor(ICommandContext context)
   � Atlassian.Bitbucket.BitbucketAuthentication..ctor(ICommandContext context)
   � Atlassian.Bitbucket.BitbucketHostProvider..ctor(ICommandContext context)
   � GitCredentialManager.Program.Main(String[] args)

����ࠡ�⠭��� �᪫�祭��: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Custom certificate bundle not found at path: D:/Программы/visual studio/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
   � GitCredentialManager.HttpClientFactory.CreateClient()
   � Atlassian.Bitbucket.OAuth2ClientRegistry..ctor(ICommandContext context)
   � Atlassian.Bitbucket.BitbucketAuthentication..ctor(ICommandContext context)
   � Atlassian.Bitbucket.BitbucketHostProvider..ctor(ICommandContext context)
   � GitCredentialManager.Program.Main(String[] args)

����ࠡ�⠭��� �᪫�祭��: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Custom certificate bundle not found at path: D:/Программы/visual studio/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
   � GitCredentialManager.HttpClientFactory.CreateClient()
   � Atlassian.Bitbucket.OAuth2ClientRegistry..ctor(ICommandContext context)
   � Atlassian.Bitbucket.BitbucketAuthentication..ctor(ICommandContext context)
   � Atlassian.Bitbucket.BitbucketHostProvider..ctor(ICommandContext context)
   � GitCredentialManager.Program.Main(String[] args)
Remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
Remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
Произошла ошибка при отправке в удаленный репозиторий: Git failed with a fatal error.
Git failed with a fatal error.
Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/git_username/git-repo.git/'

Не удалось отправить в удаленный репозиторий. Дополнительные сведения см. в окне вывода.
```

Переустанавливал через Revo Uninstaller и VS, и Git. Самое интересное, что через VSCode и Git Bash всё работает нормально, а с VS – нет

Comment: Там же написано `Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.` Используйте ключи ssh

Comment: это как? почему в VSC всё работает?

Comment: Не может там парольная авторизация работать.

Comment: простите, не пойму. как сделать то? просит username for github.com. что вводить туда? и что потом в password from username@github.com?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

Comment: да не надо ssh, получите токен в настройках и используйте вместо имени без пароля

Comment: а что VS не умеет сам OAuth2 запрашивать, что-ли? версия VS какая?

Comment: Версия 22 года. В начале VS перекидывал в браузер для авторизации в гитхабе, но это всё равно не позволяет пушить

Comment: @PavelGridin, спасибо вам, это помогло! Я сгенерировал токен на гитхабе, а когда VS запрашивал username, я ввёл его с гитхаба, а в поле password вставил токен и всё сработало!